# What is Named Notation in C?

Tags: c

I am currently learning C, and fairly new to the programming in C. I've got a question in the exercise as "does c supports named notation?" I am not able to understand what does this mean. I've tried google for answers but couldn't find any.

Comment: instead of downvoting, shed some light!

Comment: It is nonsense.It *could* mean:does C has named arguments (for functions), but without it, itis just plain nonsense.

Comment: A search for _named notation_ told me what it was and a quick look at the standard told me if it's supported. Have you tried doing this yet?

Comment: Read your course notes where it describes what they mean by "named notation"

Comment: I googled "does c supports named notation?" and the second offering is [Why do many languages not support named parameters?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219593/why-do-many-languages-not-support-named-parameters)

Comment: @WeatherVane second offering is Wikipedia here & the title is C(programming language)!

Answer (score 3):

"Named notation" usually refers to a function call syntax where parameters have names and can be passed, using those names, in any order. For instance, Python supports this language feature; it looks like:

```
foo(arg1=123, arg2=456)
```

C does not support this language feature. Arguments are purely positional.

Comment: I often implement named arguments in C using variadic macros and structs... so, if I could be petty for a moment, "named notation" can be emulated in C, even though it isn't native to the language.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is sometimes called 'named parameters'.

C doesn't support named parameters.

Some other languages do. For example [C# does](https://www.dotnetperls.com/named-parameters).